# Meaning input records Spark

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a doubt, I use Spark Streaming and I can see in the sparkUI:

I get in each microbatch 160.000 records, I can see it by SparkUI and the offsets I'm reading.(160K)
first stage which reads from Kafka I see:

```
Total Time Across All Tasks: 39 min
Locality Level Summary: Process local: 54
**Input Size / Records: 755.2 MB / 48114**
Output: 124.8 KB / 5179
```

Why isn't the input size 160K? what does it mean exactly Input Size / Records?